# How can I list all tags for a Docker image on a remote registry?

Tags: docker

How can I list all tags of a Docker image on a remote Docker registry using the CLI (preferred) or curl?

Preferably without pulling all versions from the remote registry. I just want to list the tags.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481564/how-can-i-find-docker-image-with-specific-tag-in-docker-registry-in-docker-comma/32622147#32622147

Comment: I opened a ticket asking for this feature in `docker(1)` https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/455

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a Docker image with a specific tag in Docker registry on the Docker command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481564/how-can-i-find-a-docker-image-with-a-specific-tag-in-docker-registry-on-the-dock)

Comment: while a massively newer answer I would urge you to evaluate and potentially choose this one for the newer solution with `podman` https://stackoverflow.com/a/76253905/124486

Answer (score 275, accepted):

**Update:** Docker has [deprecated the Docker Hub v1 API](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-hub-v1-api-deprecation/). To fetch tags using the [v2 API](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#tag/repositories/paths/%7E1v2%7E1namespaces%7E1%7Bnamespace%7D%7E1repositories%7E1%7Brepository%7D%7E1tags/get), use e.g.

```
wget -q -O - "https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/library/repositories/debian/tags?page_size=100" | grep -o '"name": *"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

**Note:** The results will be limited to the newest 100 tags. To get the next 100 tags, set the URL to `https://.../tags?page_size=100&page=2` etc.

For images other than Docker Official Images, replace `library` with the name of the user/organization.

The URL `https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/{namespace}/{repository}/tags` also works at the moment, however it is unclear from the API specification whether it is legal.

(If you have `jq` installed, you can replace the kludgy grep commands with `jq -r '.results[].name'`.)

---

**Original answer (v1 API, no long supported):**

I got the answer from [here](https://fordodone.com/2015/10/02/docker-get-list-of-tags-in-repository/) . Thanks  a lot! :)

Just one-line-script:(find all the tags of debian)

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/debian/tags -O -  | sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | tr '}' '\n'  | awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

---

UPDATE
Thanks for @degelf's advice.
Here is the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
cat << HELP

dockertags  --  list all tags for a Docker image on a remote registry.

EXAMPLE: 
    - list all tags for ubuntu:
       dockertags ubuntu

    - list all php tags containing apache:
       dockertags php apache

HELP
fi

image="$1"
tags=`wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/${image}/tags -O -  | sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | tr '}' '\n'  | awk -F: '{print $3}'`

if [ -n "$2" ]
then
    tags=` echo "${tags}" | grep "$2" `
fi

echo "${tags}"
```

You can just create a new file name, `dockertags`, under /usr/local/bin (or add a PATH env to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`), and put that code in it.
Then add the executable permissions(`chmod +x dockertags`).

Usage:

`dockertags ubuntu`       ---> list all tags of ubuntu

`dockertags php apache`   ---> list all php tags  php containing 'apache'

Comment: You can wrap the whole thing in echo [backtick]`...`[backtick] to condense it into one line. And/or replace "debian" with $1 and put it in a script called "dockertags" under /usr/local/bin. Then before the closing backtick you can add |grep $2. Then chmod +x it, and then you can go "dockertags php apache" to see all php tags containing apache.

Comment: `wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/circleci/ruby/tags -O - | jq -r '.[].name'` if you have `jq` installed

Comment: I've posted an [updated answer for the V2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921869/1741171).

Comment: `sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g'` is much more cleanly written `tr -d '[]" '`

Comment: I modified to use the second positional argument as username:password so that I could switch out wget for curl and use `userauth="-u ${2}"` allowing me to `${userauth}` (if it's blank no u toggle or params). This might help anyone using private repo's

Comment: what about wrapping this up into some alpine docker image? :)

Comment: How do we deal with non-docker hub images? e.g. the MS.NET core repo, i.e. mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet

Comment: For images under a user account use URL: https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/USERNAME/IMAGENAME/tags

Comment: Add a `| tail -1` to the `wget`-`jq` above to get the latest tag (as in the latest tag result, not necessarily the `latest` tag).

Comment: In 2023 it looks like `v1` is gone and `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/<image name>/tags` should be used.

Answer (score 140):

As of Docker Registry V2, a simple `GET` suffice:

```
GET /v2/<name>/tags/list
```

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/listing-image-tags) for more.

p.s. If your image registry requires authentication and you are getting an error message with the text "unauthorized", then there is a solution further down on this page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry/51921869#51921869).

Comment: Based on the info in [the Tags subsection in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags), this GET seems to require authorization, so the v1 API + `sed` appears to be actually simpler to use for a quick check...

Comment: If you're getting an "unauthorized" error, [see my alternate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921869/1741171). No offense to the person who posted the original answer. I had to take additional steps to get the answer above to work and wanted to help others.

Comment: For those who need it - if you saved your image as `a/b/c:1`, `<name>` will be `a/b/c`, so you can use `curl` to GET `/v2/a/b/c/tags/list`.

Answer (score 58):

If you want to use the docker registry v2 API, it lists tags by pages. To list all the tags of an image, you may would like to add a large page_size parameter to the url, e.g.

```
curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/centos/tags?page_size=1024'|jq '."results"[]["name"]'
```

Comment: Docker Hub appears to limit page_size to a effective maximum of 100.

Comment: @Shane Oh really? I haven't encountered an image with that many pages. Does a url like `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/centos/tags/?page=101` work?

Comment: the `java` image is a good example. Yes, you can do things like https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/java/tags/?page_size=100&page=2. See the `next` and `previous` links in the result for examples.

Comment: That `jq` expression wasn't working for me.

I used `jq '.results[].name'` instead

Comment: @Shane is correct, the page_size is 100 (at least for non-authenticated requests) - you only get 100 results even if you request more.  But it is very helpful that the tags are returned in reverse chronological order (newest first).  So if you're looking for the latest tag, you likely only need the first page.

Answer (score 39):

The [Docker Registry API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags) requires [an OAuth bearer token](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/) with the appropriate claims. In my opinion, the official documentation is rather vague on the topic. So that others don't go through the same pain I did, I offer the below `docker_tags` function.

The most recent version of `docker_tags` can be found in my [GitHub Gist: "List Docker Image Tags using bash"](https://gist.github.com/robv8r/fa66f5e0fdf001f425fe9facf2db6d49). *Editor's note: The versions have diverged.*

The docker_tags function has a dependency on [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).  If you're playing with JSON, you likely already have it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu -o pipefail
docker_tags() {
    item="$1"
    case "$item" in
        */*) :;; # namespace/repository syntax, leave as is
        *) item="library/$item";; # bare repository name (docker official image); must convert to namespace/repository syntax
    esac
    authUrl="https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$item:pull"
    token="$(curl -fsSL "$authUrl" | jq --raw-output '.token')"
    tagsUrl="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$item/tags/list"
    curl -fsSL -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "$tagsUrl" | jq --raw-output '.tags[]'
}
docker_tags "$@"
```

Example:

```
$ docker_tags "alpine"
2.6
2.7
20190228
20190408
...
3
3.1
3.10
3.10.0
3.10.1
...
3.9.5
3.9.6
edge
latest
```

Admittedly, `docker_tags` makes several assumptions. Specifically, the OAuth request parameters are mostly hard coded. A more ambitious implementation would make an unauthenticated request to the registry and derive the OAuth parameters from the unauthenticated response.

Comment: There's no need for `arr=("$@")`.  Just write `docker-tags() { for item; do ....`

Comment: Thank you for this. Getting that token was driving me nuts.

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you post a link to the documentation for whatever enables that magic?

Comment: @JakeRobb https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_03

Comment: @WilliamPursell `Omitting: in word... shall be equivalent to: in "$@" ` thanks! Sadly, that doesn't seem to be the case in zsh. 

Comment: I got authorization error using this script. However, an improved version of the script works perfectly, added as a comment: https://gist.github.com/robv8r/fa66f5e0fdf001f425fe9facf2db6d49?permalink_comment_id=3896063#gistcomment-3896063

Comment: @RobV8R: I took the liberty of making some significant changes to your script. If you don't like them, please let me know and I'll revert them and move my version to a separate answer (I just think it's better not to have multiple similar answers). If you *do* like it, consider updating your Gist and removing my "Editor's note".

Answer (score 37):

You can list all the tags with [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for json parsing through cli.

```
skopeo --override-os linux inspect docker://httpd | jq '.RepoTags'
```

```javascript
[
  "2-alpine",
  "2.2-alpine",
  "2.2.29",
  "2.2.31-alpine",
  "2.2.31",
  "2.2.32-alpine",
  "2.2.32",
  "2.2.34-alpine",
  "2.2.34",
  "2.2",
  "2.4-alpine",
  "2.4.10",
  "2.4.12",
  "2.4.16",
  "2.4.17",
  "2.4.18",
  "2.4.20",
  "2.4.23-alpine",
  "2.4.23",
  "2.4.25-alpine",
  "2.4.25",
  "2.4.27-alpine",
  "2.4.27",
  "2.4.28-alpine",
  "2.4.28",
  "2.4.29-alpine",
  "2.4.29",
  "2.4.32-alpine",
  "2.4.32",
  "2.4.33-alpine",
  "2.4.33",
  "2.4.34-alpine",
  "2.4.34",
  "2.4.35-alpine",
  "2.4.35",
  "2.4.37-alpine",
  "2.4.37",
  "2.4.38-alpine",
  "2.4.38",
  "2.4.39-alpine",
  "2.4.39",
  "2.4.41-alpine",
  "2.4.41",
  "2.4.43-alpine",
  "2.4.43",
  "2.4",
  "2",
  "alpine",
  "latest"
]
```

For external registries:

```bash
skopeo --override-os linux inspect --creds username:password docker://<registry-url>/<repo>/<image> | jq '.RepoTags'
```

Note: `--override-os linux` is only needed if you are not running on a linux host. For example, you'll have better results with it if you are on MacOS.

Comment: I see skopeo also has a `list-tags` command. Together with `jq --raw-output` you can get a plain list of tags: `skopeo --override-os linux list-tags docker://httpd | jq --raw-output .Tags[]`.

Comment: This is the easiest and clean way! Love skopeo!

Comment: I had an IBM repo which doesn't tag latest so I used this to get the info: `skopeo --override-os linux inspect docker://icr.io/cpopen/icp4a-content-operator@sha256:9005d19acc265d8e0481d133115d5f1eb8edfcae5cc22a8a774b54f969cda1ab | jq '.RepoTags'`

Answer (score 25):

If the JSON parsing tool, `jq` is available

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/debian/tags -O - | \
    jq -r '.[].name'
```

Answer (score 21):

I've managed to get it working using curl:

```
curl -u <username>:<password> https://myrepo.example/v1/repositories/<username>/<image_name>/tags
```

Note that `image_name` should not contain user details etc. For example if you're pushing image named `myrepo.example/username/x` then `image_name` should be `x`.

Comment: The v2 endpoint is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags

Comment: What is this tutum.co website that you say I should give them my dockerhub login and password?

Comment: @Nakilon When I wrote this answer, several years ago, Tutum was a service that provided a private Docker Registry. And I'm not "giving them" my password, I authenticate with their service using standard HTTP basic authentication over https.

Comment: Tutum doesn't exist anymore. Can you update your reply so people don't accidentally send their credentials to whoever owns that domain now?

Comment: I updated the answer to use `myrepo.example`.  I will need to be approved before it's updated.

Answer (score 14):

As of 2023, there are a number of tools to do this

- [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient)
- [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/)
- [crane](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/README.md)
- [reg](https://github.com/genuinetools/reg) - hasn't been updates for years, unfortunately. Doesn't work with `quay.io`.

```bash
docker run --rm ghcr.io/regclient/regctl:v0.4.5 tag ls ghcr.io/regclient/regctl      

docker run --rm quay.io/skopeo/stable:v1.9.2 list-tags docker://quay.io/skopeo/stable \
  | jq -r '.Tags[]'

docker run --rm gcr.io/go-containerregistry/crane ls gcr.io/go-containerregistry/crane  

docker run --rm r.j3ss.co/reg:v0.16.1 tags r.j3ss.co/reg
```

BTW - there are even more tools. This list looks comprehensive:
[iximiuz/awesome-container-tinkering](https://github.com/iximiuz/awesome-container-tinkering/blob/4dd6940e98c1a3571f6612e6075efd2cb1b223bb/IMAGES.md#image-distribution).

Comment: Last month, after reading your answer, I decided to give skopeo a try on my Mac, so I did "brew install skopeo". This morning, I came back to my laptop, and happily saw that brew is still working on it without any crash. I believe I will have skopeo to use in the next month =)

Comment:  You could always use it via docker, as stated in the post. For convenience an alias helps. I do that a lot, e.g. with regctl: https://github.com/schnatterer/dotfiles/blob/6329124ed6e5856de38f14de915cf907839932ce/docker/cli-tool-aliases.zsh#L19

Answer (score 11):

## `podman`

Podman is a drop-in replacement for docker with more functionality, the principal differences are that it doesn't require a daemon and does not run as root. If you are using `podman`, you can use [`podman search`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-search.1.html)

```
# podman search --list-tags <image name> --limit 1000
podman search --list-tags docker.io/alpine --limit 1000
```

There is a [`docker` command for it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/), but I couldn't find the `list-tags` option.

Comment: why does this not show the latest versions of any image?

Answer (score 10):

Building on Yan Foto's answer (the [v2 api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/listing-image-tags)), I created a [simple Python script to list the tags for a given image](https://github.com/al4/docker-registry-list).

Usage:

```
./docker-registry-list.py alpine
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "library/alpine",
  "tags": [
    "2.6",
    "2.7",
    "3.1",
    "3.2",
    "3.3",
    "3.4",
    "3.5",
    "3.6",
    "3.7",
    "edge",
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please add a license to your repo otherwise no one can use it

Answer (score 7):

See CLI utility: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-browse

Allows enumeration of tags and images.

`docker-browse tags <image>` will list all tags for the image. e.g. `docker-browse tags library/alpine`

`docker-browse images` will list all images in the registry. Not currently available for `index.docker.io`.

You may connect it to any registry, including your private one, so long as it supports Docker Registry [HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve by running on terminal this:

```
curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mysql/tags/' | jq . | grep name
```

Also, if you don't have jq you have to install it by

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Comment: `curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mysql/tags/' | jq .results[].name `
will save you a grep command

Comment: using version 1: `curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/danilobatistaqueiroz/job-wq-1/tags'`

Comment: This only returns the tags on the `:latest` image.  [@sigjuice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879158/11810933) has the `jq` form to use to retrieve *all* tags for the image.  Even then, note that only the current platform tags will be retrieved.  There may be (for example, on Python images) additional architectures and tags available beyond this list.

Comment: This only returns the tags on the `:latest` image.  [@sigjuice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879158/11810933) has the `jq` form to use to retrieve *all* tags for the image.  Also, any v2 solution is limited to 100 results per page, so for images with a large number of tags (Python currently has 1989), you'll need to implement paging.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Powershell script I wrote for Windows. Handles v1 and v2 repos:

Get-DockerImageVersions.ps1:

```
param (
  [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)]$ImageName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory=$false)]$RegistryURL
)

if (!$RegistryURL) 
{
  $RegistryURL = "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories"
}

$list = ""
if ($RegistryURL -like "*v2*") 
{
  $list = "/list"
}

$URL = "$RegistryURL/$ImageName/tags$list"

write-debug $URL
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $URL | ConvertFrom-Json

if ($RegistryURL -like "*v2*") 
{
  $tags = $resp | select tags
  $tags.tags
} else {
  $tags = $resp | select name
  $tags.name
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get all tags from Docker Hub: this command uses the command-line `JSON` processor [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) to select the tag names from the `JSON` returned by the Docker Hub Registry (the quotes are removed with `tr`). Replace *library* with the Docker Hub user name, *debian* with the image name:

```
curl -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/debian/tags/' | jq -r '."results"[]["name"]'
```

Comment: Please consider adding a small explanation as of why this answer the question, what does it do, ...

Answer (score 4):

To view all available tags in a browser:

`https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/<username>/<image_name>/tags`

i.e. https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack/tags

Or, you can get a json response using this endpoint:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/localstack/localstack/tags

Answer (score 4):

My contribution:

- Shell script
- As short and simple as possible
- Requires `curl` and `jq`
- Uses Docker v2 REST API
- Returns all tags using REST API pagination

Example:

```
$ docker-tags prantlf/chromedriver-headless
latest
102
93
86
```

Script contents:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

image=$1
if [ "$image" == "" ]; then
  echo "Usage:
  docker-tags <image>

Example:
  docker-tags library/ubuntu"
  exit 0
fi

page_size=100
page_index=0
while true; do 
  page_index=$((page_index+1))
  results=`curl -L -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$image/tags?page=$page_index&page_size=$page_size" | jq -r 'select(.results != null) | .results[]["name"]'`
  if [ $? != 0 ] || [ "$results" == "" ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "$results"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
curl -u <username>:<password> https://$your_registry/v2/$image_name/tags/list -s -o - | \
    tr -d '{' | tr -d '}' | sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | \
    awk -F: '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/,/\n/g'
```

You can use it if your env has no 'jq',  = )

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
skopeo inspect docker://<REMOTE_REGISTRY> --authfile <PULL_SECRET> | jq .RepoTags
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script that lists all tags either with 2 or 3 digits.
You can get the code directly on github
https://github.com/youssefalaoui/dockerhub-tools/blob/main/dockerhub-list-tags.sh

```
dockerhub_list_tags()
{
    #local LOCAL_IMAGE LOCAL_GET_TWO_DIGITS_VERSIONS
     
    LOCAL_IMAGE=${1:-null}
    LOCAL_GET_TWO_DIGITS_VERSIONS=${2:-true}


    if [[ $LOCAL_IMAGE == "" || $LOCAL_IMAGE == null ]]
    then
        printf "Image name is required: %s" ${FUNCNAME[0]}; 
        exit 1;
    fi

    #[[ $LOCAL_IMAGE == "" || $LOCAL_IMAGE == null ]] && printf "Image name is required: %s" ${FUNCNAME[0]}; exit 1;

    echo "Listing tags from docker hub for your image '$LOCAL_IMAGE'"
    
    # Check if 2 digits format is requested, otherwise, show it in normal format
    
    if [[ "$LOCAL_GET_TWO_DIGITS_VERSIONS" == true ]]; then
        DOCKERHUB_LIST_TAGS=($(curl -L -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$LOCAL_IMAGE/tags?page_size=1024"|jq '."results"[]["name"]' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'))
    else
        DOCKERHUB_LIST_TAGS=($(curl -L -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$LOCAL_IMAGE/tags?page_size=1024"|jq '."results"[]["name"]' | sed 's/"//g'))
    fi

    for TAG in ${DOCKERHUB_LIST_TAGS[@]}
    do
    echo $TAG
    done
}


# Test example
dockerhub_list_tags "library/nginx" false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this scrap :

```
# vim /usr/sbin/docker-tags
```

& Append Following (as it is):

```
#!/bin/bash
im="$1"
[[ -z "$im" ]] && { echo -e '\e[31m[-]\e[39m Where is the image name ??' ; exit ; }
[[ -z "$(echo "$im"| grep -o '/')" ]] && { link="https://hub.docker.com/r/library/$im/tags/" ; } || { link="https://hub.docker.com/r/$im/tags/" ; }
resp="$(curl -sL "$link")"
err="$(echo "$resp" | grep -o 'Page Not Found')"
if [[ ! -z "$err" ]] ; then
    echo -e "\e[31m[-]\e[39m No Image Found with name => [ \e[32m$im\e[39m ]"
    exit
else
    tags="$(echo "$resp"|sed  -e 's|}|\n|g' -e 's|{|\n|g'|grep '"result"'|sed -e 's|,|\n|g'|cut -d '[' -f2|cut -d ']' -f1|sed  '/"tags":/d'|sed -e 's|"||g')"
    echo -e "\e[32m$tags\e[39m"
fi
```

Make it Executable :

```
# chmod 755 /usr/sbin/docker-tags
```

Then Finally Try By :

```
$ docker-tags testexampleidontexist
   [-] No Image Found with name => [ testexampleidontexist ]

$ docker search ubuntu

$ docker-tags teamrock/ubuntu
   latest
```

*[ Hope you are aware of **$** & **#** before running any command ]*

Answer (score 2):

If folks want to read tags from the RedHat registry at `https://registry.redhat.io/v2` then the steps are:

```sh
# example nodejs-12 image
IMAGE_STREAM=nodejs-12
REDHAT_REGISTRY_API="https://registry.redhat.io/v2/rhel8/$IMAGE_STREAM"
# Get an oAuth token based on a service account username and password https://access.redhat.com/articles/3560571
TOKEN=$(curl --silent -u "$REGISTRY_USER":"$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "https://sso.redhat.com/auth/realms/rhcc/protocol/redhat-docker-v2/auth?service=docker-registry&client_id=curl&scope=repository:rhel:pull" |  jq --raw-output '.token')
# Grab the tags
wget -q --header="Accept: application/json" --header="Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -O - "$REDHAT_REGISTRY_API/tags/list" | jq -r '."tags"[]'
```

If you want to compare what you have in your local openshift registry against what is in the upstream registry.redhat.com then here is a [complete script](https://gist.github.com/simbo1905/91750dd041e48bb816293b3bf964fe12).

Answer (score 2):

In powershell 5.1, I have a simple *list_docker_image_tags.ps1* script like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $image
)

$url = "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/{0}/tags" -f $image 
Invoke-WebRequest $url  | ConvertFrom-Json | Write-Output
```

Then I can grep for 4.7 tags like this:

```
./list_docker_image_tags.ps1 microsoft/dotnet-framework | ?{ $_.name -match "4.7" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that's applicable for v2 of the registry.

If you have `jq` and `curl` installed on your machine:

```sh
curl https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$REPOSITORY/tags?page_size=10000 | jq '.results[] | { name: .name, architectures: ([ (.images[] | if .variant? then .os + "/" + .architecture + .variant? else .os + "/" + .architecture end) ] | join(", ")) }'
```

For instance, running this command for the `curlimages/curl` repository yields:

```json
{
  "name": "latest",
  "architectures": "linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/arm64, linux/386, linux/armv7, linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.78.0",
  "architectures": "linux/armv7, linux/arm64, linux/386, linux/s390x, linux/ppc64le, linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.77.0",
  "architectures": "linux/ppc64le, linux/arm64, linux/s390x, linux/armv7, linux/386, linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.76.1",
  "architectures": "linux/386, linux/arm64, linux/armv7, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.76.0",
  "architectures": "linux/armv7, linux/386, linux/s390x, linux/amd64, linux/ppc64le, linux/arm64"
}
{
  "name": "7.75.0",
  "architectures": "linux/armv7, linux/ppc64le, linux/386, linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/s390x"
}
{
  "name": "7.74.0",
  "architectures": "linux/armv7, linux/386, linux/amd64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/arm64"
}
{
  "name": "7.73.0",
  "architectures": "linux/arm64, linux/armv7, linux/s390x, linux/ppc64le, linux/amd64, linux/386"
}
{
  "name": "7.72.0",
  "architectures": "linux/s390x, linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/386, linux/ppc64le, linux/armv7"
}
{
  "name": "7.71.1",
  "architectures": "linux/s390x, linux/arm64, linux/ppc64le, linux/amd64, linux/386, linux/armv7"
}
{
  "name": "7.71.0",
  "architectures": "linux/arm64, linux/ppc64le, linux/386, linux/s390x, linux/amd64, linux/armv7"
}
{
  "name": "7.70.0",
  "architectures": "linux/386, linux/arm64, linux/s390x, linux/amd64, linux/ppc64le, linux/armv7"
}
{
  "name": "7.69.1",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.69.0",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.68.0",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.67.0",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.66.0",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
{
  "name": "7.65.3",
  "architectures": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Comment: Useful, but keep in mind that V2 responses are limited to 100 results per page (the `page_size=10000` has no effect above 100).  You'll need to implement paging to be sure of all results.  Python, for instance, currently has 1989 tags.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of duplication among the answers given thus far.
Most of them fail to take into account that the Docker Hub API (at least v2) will never return more than 100 results at a time, even if you ask for more. I noticed this when requesting the tags for [`php`](https://hub.docker.com/_/php).

[The following script](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erp/bin/dockertags) works around this.
It only works for public repositories.

```
#!/bin/sh

# list the tags on Docker Hub for the given image(s)
# thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry

TagsFor()
{
  curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/'$1'/tags?page='$2'&page_size'=$3
}

for i in "$@"
do
  TagsFor "$i" 1 10 |
  jq -r .count |
  while read nr_of_tags
  do
    nr_of_pages=`expr $nr_of_tags / 100`
    seq 1 $nr_of_pages |
    while read p
    do
      TagsFor "$i" "$p" 100 |
      jq -r '.results[] | .name'
    done
  done
done
```

I just ran the script; it retrieved 7200 `php` tags. For all I know, it may be running into yet another API limit, but 7200 >> 100.

Comment: Why do you mention GitHub API?

Comment: No idea. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: PS: when I wrote this answer, I wasn't aware of `docker search`.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker Registry API has an endpoint to [list all tags](http://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags).

Looks like Tutum has a [similar endpoint](https://docs.tutum.co/v2/api/#list-all-tags), as well as a way to access via [tutum-cli](https://docs.tutum.co/v2/api/?shell#list-all-tags).

With the tutum-cli, try the following:

```
tutum tag list <uuid>
```

Comment: I don't think this works for registry images. I just get a "Identifier '<id>' does not match any service, node or nodecluster".

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
In answer to the question:

> How can I list all tags of a Docker image on a remote Docker registry using the CLI (preferred) or curl?
>
> Preferably without pulling all versions from the remote registry. I just want to list the tags.

To get all the tags for an image you can use "curl" to get the specific image you want and pipe the output into "[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)" to extract the information.

```
curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/python/tags?page_size=1024'|jq  '.results[]["name"]'
```

Output (truncated not the full list):

```
"3.9-windowsservercore"  
"alpine3.14"  
"alpine3.13"  
"alpine"  
"3.9.8-alpine3.14"  
"3.9.8-alpine3.13"
"3.9.8-alpine"
```

Further should you need additional information from the registry you can access additional field information like this.

This command will give you both the tags and the size of the image which might be useful to have too.

```
curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/python/tags?page_size=1024'|jq  '.results[] as $results | ($results["name"] + " - " + ($results["full_size"] | tostring))'
```

Output (truncated not the full list):

```
 "3.9-windowsservercore - 2241040278"  
 "alpine3.14 - 17565702"  
 "alpine3.13 - 17556181"  
 "alpine - 17565702"  
 "3.9.8-alpine3.14 -17362557"  
 "3.9.8-alpine3.13 - 17353629"  
 "3.9.8-alpine - 17362557"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Or to list just the tags: `curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/python/tags?page_size=1024' | jq '.results[] | .name'`, and use `jq -r` to get rid of the quotes.

Comment: At least right now, pages sizes larger than 100 are equivalent to 100 - more results will not be supplied. However, the JSON contains a link to a next page, which can of course be followed to obtain more results.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @AlexForbes's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49495136/4933641) I've improved the api v2 docker-registry-list.py to support:
  – slashes in the repository name (eg curlimages/curl) and
  – private repos (authentication by username and password)

https://github.com/axil/docker-registry-list

Usage:

```
./docker-registry-list.py -u dockerid -p password dockerid/myrepo
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "dockerid/myrepo",
  "tags": [
    "1.0"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you must add an open source license

Comment: @aehlke The original code does not have a license. "Without a license, the default copyright laws apply, meaning that you retain all rights to your source code and no one may reproduce, distribute, or create derivative works from your work." ([github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/licensing-a-repository)). Not only I am not eligible to add a license, but I am also not allowed to even create any derivatives, let alone publish them. I've published them on my own risk and can potentially be sued for this.

Comment: I know code must have a license to redistribute, that's why I asked - I missed that this isn't your work and have asked the original author

Comment: @aehlke Yes, that's the right question to ask. I would only object to the word 'must' ;) Would it be my own work, I could potentially add a more restrictive license than 'open source'.

Comment: Anyway, I raised an issue in @AlexForbes repository and he added the license and I merged it in.

Comment: ty 123456789012

Answer (score 0):

I have done this thing when I have to implement a task in which if user somehow type the wrong tag then we have to give the list of all the tag present in the repo(Docker repo) present in the register.
So I have code in batch Script.

```
<html>
<pre style="background-color:#bcbbbb;">
@echo off

docker login --username=xxxx --password=xxxx
docker pull %1:%2

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
echo "Specified Version is Not Found "
echo "Available Version for this image is :"
for /f %%i in (' curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"password\"}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login ^|jq -r .token ') do set TOKEN=%%i
curl -sH "Authorization: JWT %TOKEN%" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/%1/tags/" | jq .results[].name
)
</pre>
</html>
```

So in this we can give arguments to out batch file like:

```
Dockerfile java version7
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for an sdk in java that I could use to hit the `Docker V2 API` but couldn't find one. Repo here for anyone that might find it useful: https://github.com/fern-api/docker-registry-api.

Should be possible to generate in other languages too, feel free to open an issue on the repo!