# Get list of docker tags available to pull from command line?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to get some basic information about the published versions/tags of a docker image, to know what image:tag's I can pull. I would also like to see the time that each tag was most recently published.

Is there a way to do this on the command line?

```
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
```

Basically looking for the equivalent of `npm info {pkg}` for a docker image.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/28320134/355438 help you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not from the command line. You have `docker search` but it only returns a subset of the data you want, and only for the image with the `:latest` tag:

```
> docker search sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet
NAME                    DESCRIPTION                        STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet   Hadoop with .NET Core installed    1                    [OK]
```

If you want more detail, you'll need to use the [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), but it only has a catalog endpoint for listing repositories, the [issue for search](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/206) is still open.

Assuming you know the repository name, you can navigate the API - first you need an auth token:

```
> curl "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet:pull"
{"token":"eyJhbG...
```

Then you pass the token to subsequent requests, e.g. to list the tags:

```
> curl --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJh..." https://index.docker.io/v2/sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet/tags/list
{"name":"sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet","tags":["2.7.2","latest"]}
```

And then get all the information about one image by its repository name and tag:

```
> curl --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJh..." https://index.docker.io/v2/sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet/manifests/latest
```

Comment: Can you add a sample response for the final request?

Comment: It's 170 lines of JSON... Starts: `{                                                                                                                                                                
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "sixeyed/hadoop-dotnet",
   "tag": "latest",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      }...`

Answer (score 5):

> I want to get some basic information about the published versions/tags of a docker image, to know what image:tag's I can pull.

This is from the [tags/list API](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#content-discovery). Here's a small script that does it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ref="${1:-library/ubuntu:latest}"
repo="${ref%:*}"
tag="${ref##*:}"
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/tags/list" | jq .
```

Running that looks like:

```
$ ./tags-v2.sh library/ubuntu:latest
{                                   
  "name": "library/ubuntu",         
  "tags": [                         
    "10.04",                        
    "12.04",                        
    "12.04.5",                      
    "12.10",                        
    "13.04",                        
    "13.10",                        
    "14.04",                        
    "14.04.1",      
...
```

> I would also like to see the time that each tag was most recently published.

You likely want to pull the [image config](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/config.md) for this. First you need to pull the manifest, parse the config descriptor, then pull that blob for the config json. Here's a script that will do that for docker images:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ref="${1:-library/ubuntu:latest}"
repo="${ref%:*}"
tag="${ref##*:}"
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')
digest=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
              -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${tag}" \
         | jq -r .config.digest)
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -s -L "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/blobs/${digest}" | jq .
```

And an example of running that script:

```
$ ./get-config-v2.sh library/ubuntu:latest
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "bash"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:6c18a628d47eacf574eb93da2324293a0e6c845084cca2ea13efaa3cee4d0799",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  "container": "249e88be79ad9986a479c71c15a056946ae26b0c54c1f634f115be6d5f9ba1c8",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "249e88be79ad",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "#(nop) ",
      "CMD [\"bash\"]"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:6c18a628d47eacf574eb93da2324293a0e6c845084cca2ea13efaa3cee4d0799",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {}
  },
  "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.578710012Z",
  "docker_version": "20.10.7",
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.226745473Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653c93d3a0b262a28112d47a46326ff5fc2dfbf7fa3b9a0ce8 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.578710012Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"bash\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:9f54eef412758095c8079ac465d494a2872e02e90bf1fb5f12a1641c0d1bb78b"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that this will only give you details from the build tooling, the registry itself does not track when an image was uploaded to that registry from any OCI APIs (some registries may add their own metadata, but this would be registry specific).

---

To handle more authentication types, different kinds of images (OCI vs Docker), and similar, I've packaged these commands and more into `regctl` in the [regclient project](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/). Similar projects exist from Google's container registry crane command, and RedHat's skopeo, each giving access to registries from the command line:

```
$ regctl tag ls ubuntu
10.04           
12.04           
12.04.5         
12.10           
13.04           
13.10           
14.04           
14.04.1         
14.04.2         
14.04.3         
14.04.4         
14.04.5      
...

$ regctl image config ubuntu
{
  "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.578710012Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "bash"
    ]
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:9f54eef412758095c8079ac465d494a2872e02e90bf1fb5f12a1641c0d1bb78b"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.226745473Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d68d27cc15a80653c93d3a0b262a28112d47a46326ff5fc2dfbf7fa3b9a0ce8 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-10-16T00:37:47.578710012Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"bash\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a token:

```sh
curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/<$repo_name>/tags?page=<$page_nb>&page_size=<$page_size>' | jq '."results"[]["name"]'
```

Where you can get `<$repo_name>` with:

```sh
docker search <$expression>
```

---

For example:

```sh
$ docker search piwigo
NAME                        DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
linuxserver/piwigo          A Piwigo container, brought to you by LinuxS…   152                  
mathieuruellan/piwigo       Easy deployment of piwigo for my personal us…   19                   [OK]
lsioarmhf/piwigo                                                            3                    
hg8496/piwigo                                                               2                    [OK]
[…]

$ curl -L -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/linuxserver/piwigo/tags?page=1&page_size=10' | jq '."results"[]["name"]'
"latest"
"12.0.0"
"version-12.0.0"
"12.0.0-ls137"
"arm64v8-12.0.0"
"arm32v7-12.0.0"
"amd64-12.0.0"
"arm64v8-version-12.0.0"
"arm32v7-version-12.0.0"
"amd64-version-12.0.0"
```

---

*Source: [Démarrer avec les containers Docker](https://blog.stephane-robert.info/post/introduction-docker/)*