# Pulling Docker Images - Manifest not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to download a tagged docker image

```
docker pull clkao/postgres-plv8:10-2
```

and, in a compose file,

```
  postgres:
    image: clkao/postgres-plv8:10-2
```

But receive a `manifest not found` exception.

Unless I'm mistaken, [that tag exists](https://hub.docker.com/r/clkao/postgres-plv8/) in Docker Hub, however I notice that it doesn't appear on the [tags list](https://hub.docker.com/r/clkao/postgres-plv8/tags/).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this perhaps an issue with Docker Hub or the way that repo has been set up?

If it isn't 'my fault', what's a recommendation to move forward? Create my own Dockerfile perhaps?

Comment: Docker version?

Comment: Hi. Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40. Would that make a difference to what tags are discoverable?

Comment: See answer that says it just doesn't exist. That was my problem in getting this error. I had `ubuntu:20.4` when I meant `ubuntu:20.04`. So, I'd suggest checking if the tag exist on docker hub first.

Answer (score 23):

You might also try
`docker pull -a <image>`.
The `-a` will pull all versions of that image, which at least lets you know what is there.

(This is less useful if you really need a specific version, but helped me when I tried to pull an image that for some reason did not have a 'latest' tag.)

**Edit**:  This is actually a really *bad* idea, since it will pull down the entire history, which for many repositories could be many GB.  Better to go look at the repository site and see what tag you want.   Note to self: don't post answers when you are tired.  :-(

Comment: There was insane amount of cleanup after using `-a` flag with Ubuntu. It did give me visibility to my issue though. I for one was simply targeting the wrong Ubuntu by leaving out a zero on the minor. In the end it wasn't `ubuntu:20.4`, but `ubuntu:20.04` to overcome this error/block.

Comment: It is better to get a list of all tags of that image, rather than pulling them all. Check out this question about getting a list of all tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry

Comment: @ge333 thanks for that!  From the varied answers it looks like it is a bit complicated to set up properly, but it certainly is preferable to have just the tags and not all the images.

Answer (score 15):

You get the error message because there exist no tag with "10-2".
You can try to figure out why and contact the repository owner or you can try to build your own one.

Answer (score 7):

I just got over this "manifest for / not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry."

Using

```
docker login <repo>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use docker pull, without a tag, it will default to the tag `:latest`. Make sure that when we are building a image add tag latest or we can access the image by the tag name after image name with colon

Answer (score 1):

Basically ***`" manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry. "`*** when used old tags of any docker image that time this issue occur , please check tags are valid or not on that image and then re-rerun with new /updated docker image.

***Hope it will work .. Enjoy the work ....!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Check the docker's image also not only that the tag exists,  I was trying to run Flyway version 5.0.1 for an image flyway/flyway which version did not exist, it existed only in version flyway/flyway:latest it seems, whereas 5.0.1 existed and I pulled it but in/from a different repository name, with repository name boxfuse/flyway.

for the error message 'docker manifest unknown'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to tag your image as v8.10.2. Make sure while tagging image locally you use same tag which you want to pull in future. So steps will  be like below:

- docker build -t clkao/postgres-pl:v8.10.2 .
- docker push clkao/postgres-pl:v8.10.2
- docker pull clkao/postgres-pl:v8.10.2

Answer (score 0):

If this is from Git via `docker.pkg.github.com` then you need to switch to use `ghcr.io`. The former is deprecated and does not support the manifest endpoint so some docker clients, when they attempt to download various resources, fail with this error message. If you instead publish your image to ghcr (Github Container Repository), the docker image pulling process should complete successfully.

```sh
cd <dir with Dockerfile in it>
docker build -f Dockerfile -t ghcr.io/<org_id>/<project_id>:<version> .
docker push ghcr.io/<org_id>/<project_id>:<version>
```

More info here: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/migrating-to-the-container-registry-from-the-docker-registry

> Note: The Container registry is currently in public beta and subject
> to change. During the beta, storage and bandwidth are free. To use the
> Container registry, you must enable the feature preview. For more
> information, see "Introduction to GitHub Packages" and "Enabling
> improved container support with the Container registry."

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happended with our internal registry. I simply pushed again the image and pulled afterwards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).