# API for redhat base image to get values of image tags?

Tags: docker, redhat-containers

Do we have an API to programmatically get the value of image tags for the below image?

```
https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=tags&get-method=registry-tokens#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7
```

Use case:
Grab the later version if a new tag version is available.

I'm looking for something like below:

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/debian/tags -O -  | sed -e 's/[][]//g' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/ //g' | tr '}' '\n'  | awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

The above solution is from the stackoverflow question:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry
```

I did

```
wget https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=tags&get-method=registry-tokens#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7
```

Unfortunately, it gives a lot of redundant data which does not help.

I appreciate any lead.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `skopeo` command to get information about the remote image. For example, if you run:

```
skopeo inspect docker://registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7
```

You'll get back a chunk of JSON data that includes information about all of the available tags:

```
{
    "Name": "registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7",
    "Digest": "sha256:11ec91dcb3505f6eaa02d815fab39078786f3ddbef26796e3ef348410ca43b9d",
    "RepoTags": [
        "7.3-74",
        "7.4-120",
        "7.2-56",
        "7.3-89",
        "7.3-66",
        "7.5-424",
        "7.5-245.1527091554",
        "7.4-129",
        "7.1-12",
        "7.6-122",
        "7.3-82",
        "7.7-384.1575996163",
        "7.5-409.1533127727",
        "7.2-75",
        "7.2-38",
        "7.6",
[...]
```

(There are about 70 total.)

Since `skopeo` returns JSON results, it's easy to take this output and programatically parse it to extract the information you want.

---

Using the debug output from `skopeo` (`skopeo --debug ...`), I see that the list of tags is also available from `https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/rhel7/tags/list`. That appears to work without authentication, so maybe that is the simplest option.

Comment: Sir, yes I know about skopeo but the bitter reality is I am having 0 luck to have it installed on EC2 (Amazon Linux 2). I am using EC2 t2.medium

Comment: Then use the HTTP API I referred to in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Picture perfect! Yep, the url which you gave works like a charm! Thanks, heaps :)