# How to pull docker hub images with tag name as a regex

Tags: docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

**Requirement:**
Let's say I have below listed images in docker hub:

- imagename:gvh
- imagename:vidgvh
- imagename:gvhjeevi
- imagename:herogvh

How do I pull all these images with varying tag names but contains a common subpattern with one docker pull command?

For aws ecr, we have to run below command, but for docker hub no such option available.

`aws ecr list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecr:region:account_id:repository/repository_name`

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/list-tags-for-resource.html

```
docker pull imagename:<regex-tag>
```

Comment: You need to write a script around the techniques in [How can I list all tags for a Docker image on a remote registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry); there is no built-in support for that in Docker.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use pipe of several different commands.
Below is the example:

```
curl https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mysql/tags \
   | jq -r '.[].name' \
   | grep "8.0" \
   | xargs -i docker pull mysql:{}
```

You can also use regular expressions in grep command.

Comment: getting 'xargs: pull: No such file or directory' error