# get last pushed tag name for the docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-repository

I want to get the last pushed tag number for the docker image. For ex: we are maintaining tag incremental version lik e0.1, 0.2 ..0.n everytime we push the image to the registry.
If last pushed tag version is 0.2, I need to get the last pushed tag(0.2) before pushing the new version(0.3) because i have a requirement to increase tag version automatically through pipeline.
is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: what did you find so far during your research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all tags for a Docker image on a remote registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry)

Comment: this list all the tags..but my requirement is to get the last pushed tag number(for ex 0.7) and push the new images with the tag(0.8) automatically in pipeline.

Comment: If you retrieve all tags then you can get the share of the tag `latest` and compare it with the shas of all the tags. When you find a tag that has matching sha with latest then you know that it is the newest version. This is of course assuming you maintain a latest tag.

Comment: Or just order the versions. Assuming you are using jenkins, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy) might help.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes im usinng jenkins... how do i use this script(compare-version-strings-in-groovy) in jenkins file? i dont find any samples available online @msg

Comment: Add it as a [library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Although not exactly the same, [here's a tutorial](https://etoews.github.io/blog/2020/02/18/semver-comparison-in-a-jenkins-pipeline/) on something similar. You can also google for "jenkins semver".