# Docker - Build an image using another image as a base

Tags: docker

I have a hierarchy of images/services that I am trying to build. There is a base image, which all other images/services will use when they themselves are being built. I need to make changes to the base image, to test whether these changes will affect the other images/services. The hierarchy can be thought of as something like this:

```
base-image
    base-image-variant
        services
```

My question is, how to I ensure changes to the base image will be included when I build a service based on that base image? I have tried building them using the same tag but I am not sure if this works. Will tagging the base image and the other images/services with the same tag work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two basic approaches that will work here.

If you use a "floating" tag, then [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) has a `--pull` option that always pulls the `FROM` image before it does the build.  This will ensure it gets updates, and is easy to set up; but, you don't necessarily have a known chain of versions from end to end, if this is important to you.  (This also applies to Docker Hub images like `ubuntu:20.04` that get regular security updates, but not necessarily to specific-patch-release versions of images like `python:3.10.3` which will never get any update at all.)

```sh
FROM registry.example.com/base-image-variant:latest
```

```sh
docker build --pull -t registry.example.com/services .
```

The other thing you can do is give a distinct tag to every build of every image.  This is a good practice, especially in environments like Kubernetes, since it's easy to know what exact build you're using and what builds it depends on, and it's easy to downgrade something by going back to yesterday's tag.  But, actually finding the most recent tag is a harder problem than it sounds (see, for example, [How can I list all tags for a Docker image on a remote registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-can-i-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry)).

```sh
ARG base_tag=latest
FROM registry.example.com/base-image-variant:${base_tag}
```

```sh
docker build \
  --build-arg base_tag=20220407 \
  -t registry.example.com/services:20220410 \
  .
```

If your CI system can ensure that every base image is (re)built before every service image then it's fine to use the same tags, but it's not strictly required.