# Listing the tags of a Docker image on a Docker hub through the HTTP API

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I would like to list the tags of a Docker image official Docker hub through its HTTP interface, but I am a bit confused. As there seems to two versions of them:

- https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/reference/api/registry_api/
- https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/registry/spec/api/

I managed to get them through sending a GET request to this endpoint: `https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/{my-namespace}/{my-repository}/tags` along with basic authentication credentials.

I am not sure if there is a correct one among them, but which should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker made a huge refactor of the registry: registry v2.0.

With this brand new version, comes a new authentication system so the basic auth of v1.0 will not work anymore.

You can find more details about the v2.0 auth here: https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/registry/spec/auth/token/

As v1.0 is deprecated, you should move forward to registry v2.0.

Answer (score 5):

I'm arriving a little late, I searched this question as list all tags for the same image (understand digest), unfortunately most of the answers are only about displaying all available tags for any image digest that was pushed.

Case in hand, for open jdk the same image digest is usually tagged multiple times :

```
  {
    "sha256:518f6c2137b7463272cb1f52488e914b913b92bfe0783acb821c216987959971": [
      "11",
      "11-buster",
      "11-jdk",
      "11-jdk-buster",
      "11.0",
      "11.0-buster",
      "11.0-jdk",
      "11.0-jdk-buster",
      "11.0.8",
      "11.0.8-buster",
      "11.0.8-jdk",
      "11.0.8-jdk-buster"
    ]
  },
```

I wasn't able to find the relevant API v2, it seems the api exposes tags, but there's no details and otherwise you need to list each blob manifest to get matching digest via the response header `Docker-Content-Digest`. I Unless I missed something this unusable for my use case when there is a lot of tags, so I just used the *regular* dockerhub API to get all tags and teir details and group these tags by the image digest.

```
(
  url="https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/openjdk/tags/?page_size=100" ;
  while [ -n "$url" ]; do
    >&2 echo -n ".";
    content="$(curl -s "$url")";
    url=$(jq -r '.next // empty' <<< "${content}");
    echo "$content";
  done;
  >&2 echo;
) | jq -s '[.[].results[]]' \
  | jq 'map({tag: .name, digest: .images[].digest}) | unique | group_by(.digest) | map(select(.[].digest) | {(.[0].digest): [.[].tag]})' \
  > openjdk-tags.json
```

I've published this as a script in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bric3/f8ebbe444704a3a7a05d3fd952c32129), any comment or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to send a thank you for the script, it's great!

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Docker V2 API**

The Docker V2 API requires an OAuth bearer token with the appropriate claims. In my opinion, the official documentation is rather vague on the topic. So that others don't go through the same pain I did, I offer the below `docker-tags` function.

The most recent version of `docker-tags` can be found in my [GitHubGist : "List Docker Image Tags using bash"](https://gist.github.com/robv8r/fa66f5e0fdf001f425fe9facf2db6d49).

The docker-tags function has a dependency on [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).  If you're playing with JSON, you likely already have it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker-tags() {
    arr=("$@")

    for item in "${arr[@]}";
    do
        tokenUri="https://auth.docker.io/token"
        data=("service=registry.docker.io" "scope=repository:$item:pull")
        token="$(curl --silent --get --data-urlencode ${data[0]} --data-urlencode ${data[1]} $tokenUri | jq --raw-output '.token')"
        listUri="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$item/tags/list"
        authz="Authorization: Bearer $token"
        result="$(curl --silent --get -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" $listUri | jq --raw-output '.')"
        echo $result
    done
}
```

Example

```
docker-tags "microsoft/nanoserver" "microsoft/dotnet" "library/mongo" "library/redis"
```

Admittedly, `docker-tags` makes several assumptions. Specifically, the OAuth request parameters are mostly hard coded. A more ambitious implementation would make an unauthenticated request to the registry and derive the OAuth parameters from the unauthenticated response.

Comment: you declare but do not use `authz`.  Also no need to assign and echo `result`, you could just let jq output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Bash script to do just that. Save it to a file named docker-hub-tags-list and run it like this:

```
docker-hub-tags-list markriggins/todowrangler
```

But you need to be logged in via `docker login` first. And you will need to install the JSON tool http://trentm.com/json/ which is a very cool tool for parsing JSON on the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REPOSITORY=${REPOSITORY:-$1}
REGISTRY=${REGISTRY:-docker.io}

#
#  Docker funcs
#
    d__docker_relative_repository_name_from_URL() {
        # Given $REGISTRY/repo/path:tag, return the repo/path
        set +o pipefail
        echo ${1-} | sed -e "s|^$REGISTRY/||" | cut -d: -f1
    }

    d___version_sort() {
        # Read stdin, sort by version number descending, and write stdout
        # It assumes X.Y.Z version numbers

        # This will sort tags like pr-3001, pr-3002 to the END of the list
        # and tags like 2.1.4 BEFORE 2.1.4-gitsha

        sort -s -t- -k 2,2nr |  sort -t. -s -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr
    }

    d__basic_auth() {
        #
        # Read basic authentication credentials from `docker login`
        #
        cat ~/.docker/config.json | json '.auths["https://index.docker.io/v1/"].auth'
    }


    d__registry__tags_list() {

        # Return a list of available tags for the given repository sorted
        # by version number, descending
        #
        # Get tags list from dockerhub using the v2 API and an auth.docker token

        local rel_repository=$(d__docker_relative_repository_name_from_URL ${1})
        [ -z "$rel_repository" ] && return

        local TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $(d__basic_auth)" \
                       -H 'Accept: application/json' \
                       "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$rel_repository:pull" | json .token)


        curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json" \
                "https://index.docker.io/v2/$rel_repository/tags/list" |
                json .tags |
                json -a |
                d___version_sort
    }

d__registry__tags_list $REPOSITORY
```

Answer (score 2):

### private image repositories, v2 API

A version that works with private and public repositories, written in vanilla Bourne shell (including, but not limited to Bash), and using the v2 API, lives at https://gist.github.com/nealey/86da928cdb5c21a4edc1be2ba7b845e3

You can run it like:

```
$ docker-tags.sh alpine
$ docker-tags.sh ceph/daemon
$ docker-tags.sh quay.io/coreos/dnsmasq
```

It lists all versions, one per line.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

image="$1"; shift
if [ -z "$image" ] || [ "$image" == "--help" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 IMAGE"
    echo
    echo "Prints all tags associated with IMAGE in a docker repository"
    exit 1
fi

case "$image" in
    */*/*)
        host=${image%%/*/*}
        path=${image#*/}
        ;;
    */*)
        host=index.docker.io
        path=$image
        ;;
    *)
        host=index.docker.io
        path=library/$image
        ;;
esac

tags_uri=https://$host/v2/$path/tags/list

##
## Figure out who hands out tokens by doing an unauthenticated request
##
extract () {
    # XXX: This can't handle values with commas in them
    echo -n "$2" | awk -v f="$1" 'BEGIN {RS=","; FS="=\"|\"$";} ($1 == f) { print $2; }'
}
auth=$(curl --silent -I $tags_uri | sed -n 's/^Www-Authenticate: Bearer //p' | tr -d '\r')
if [ -n "$auth" ]; then
    realm=$(extract realm "$auth")
    service=$(extract service "$auth")
    scope=$(extract scope "$auth")
    ## Now fetch a token
    token=$(curl --silent --get --data-urlencode "service=$service" --data-urlencode "scope=$scope" $realm | jq  -r '.token')
    auth_header="Authorization: Bearer $token"
fi

## Finally, list versions
curl -s --header "$auth_header" "$tags_uri" | jq -r '.tags[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Neale Picket for your script.
It wasn't working for me for private repositories, so I edited it a little (and also fixed a problem with case sensitive on headers detection)

This one asks for your Dockerhub user and password at the very beginning, and use it to make and authenticated request to Dockehuv API.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/juanlb/b959354cc289dd9962e9f57dee4ac063