# Why is this refresh token request to auth.docker.io returning a 404?

Tags: docker, refresh, token

I am trying to use the api documented here: https://docker.github.io/registry/spec/auth/oauth/

When I POST to the service as described in the docs, it always returns a 404.

I've tried this using my own account and also using the exact query in the documentation.

Here is an example:

```
[prompt]$ curl -v \

-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w&service=hub.docker.io&client_id=dockerengine&access_type=offline' \
https://auth.docker.io/token
* Trying 52.5.234.85...
* Connected to auth.docker.io (52.5.234.85) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.docker.io
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: auth.docker.io
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: /
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 118

upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 01:10:14 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< 
404 page not found
Connection #0 to host auth.docker.io left intact
```

The same response is returned when using credentials for an active account.
It seems that I should at least receive a 401 if the account not authenticated.

Is this service no longer supported?

There is a GET api that I can use to acquire a short-lived bearer token, but I need a refresh token.
That GET api is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/jwt/

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. I'll put the solution first, with extra info later.

```
DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME=$1
DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD=$2
DOCKER_REPO=$3

AUTH_64=$(echo -n $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME:$DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD | base64)

TOKEN=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $AUTH_64" \
                -H 'Accept: application/json' \
                "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$DOCKER_REPO:pull" | jq -r .token)

curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json" \
    "https://index.docker.io/v2/$DOCKER_REPO/tags/list" | jq -r .tags
```

I did some digging and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361077/listing-the-tags-of-a-docker-image-on-a-docker-hub-through-the-http-api/38277663#38277663) which required you to use docker login, which isn't what I wanted. After looking into the docker conf file he was pulling from, I figured out the value was the base64 encoding of `user:pass`. So I just avoid trying to get a refresh token.

I used jq to get the json values. [Here is a download link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/). You can retrieve them however you want. I placed the second command in as an example, although this should work with anything from [the v2 API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/). I think you can even replace `index.docker.io` with any docker registry.

Oh, if you need push access be sure to change `$DOCKER_REPO:pull` to `$DOCKER_REPO:pull,push`

Comment: I have experimented with the GET api, which provides a short-lived bearer token. The question is asking for a solution for acquiring refresh tokens.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't answer that directly. I believe it is currently broken or depreciated. The docker apis seem to have a lot of outdated or conflicting information. I wasn't sure if just needed to be able to run commands and authenticate based on a user account or if you specifically wanted the refresh token. I hope it gets fixed soon.