# How to Get All Tags from Docker Hub (Private Repositories) as Shell Script

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have one shell script when i execute it showing only 64 tags from 300 tags docker hub.

Here is the below command which i'm executing in shell script through curl.

```
IMAGE_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${HUB_TOKEN} https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$username/issues/tags/?page_size=300" | jq --raw-output '.results[] | .name')
```

Even after giving page_size also it is not showing my all tags

Note :- Tags using for Private Repositories

Please help me how can i solve it

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask), more specifically the paragraph telling you **not to include code, commands, and error messages in images**. Then please edit your question and fix this. Doing so makes the post harder to read, breaks copy/paste if needed, and hides the content from search engines (SO internal and others). Thanks.

Comment: please describe it little more and add the command in question

Comment: @DupinderSingh shall i share u completed script and i have made changes in above question

Comment: @Zeitounator please have a look my question changes made it

Comment: @MohdRashid There is absolutely no added value to post the image. You should add code block markers (i.e. three backticks before and after code) so that your code displays correctly. Have a look at the top editor controls and the help on the left column when editing your question.

Comment: @Zeitounator i have remove image and added backticks to it

Comment: @MohdRashid  Are you able to cal through the browser and able to get the result

Answer (score 0):

Try API version 1 which help me to get all the tags

`https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mysql/tags` open in browser and you can modify it as per your need

Or have a look to Github https://gist.github.com/robv8r/fa66f5e0fdf001f425fe9facf2db6d49 This is exactly what you want

**UPDATE**

Add this in a shell script file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker-tags() {
    arr=("$@")

    for item in "${arr[@]}";
    do
        tokenUri="https://auth.docker.io/token"
        data=("service=registry.docker.io" "scope=repository:$item:pull")
        token="$(curl --silent --get --data-urlencode ${data[0]} --data-urlencode ${data[1]} $tokenUri | jq --raw-output '.token')"
        listUri="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$item/tags/list"
        authz="Authorization: Bearer $token"
        result="$(curl --silent --get -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" $listUri | jq --raw-output '.')"
        echo $result
    done
}

docker-tags "<YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>"
```

Replace  `<YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>` with your docker image.

have a look to this for more info [Listing the tags of a Docker image on a Docker hub through the HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361077/listing-the-tags-of-a-docker-image-on-a-docker-hub-through-the-http-api)

Comment: https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/rashidmd/fx-test2/tags i modify it and open in browser its asking username and password for which i have given but incorrect telling me and i got error when i added v1 in place of v2  "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8"

Comment: is this your private container registry?

Comment: if you know the credentials then put it right  It should work. Because it is working for public repos

Comment: after giving correct username and password its again coming back with username and password

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361077/listing-the-tags-of-a-docker-image-on-a-docker-hub-through-the-http-api try this s

Comment: IMAGE_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${HUB_TOKEN}" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mohd/issues/tags/?page_size=30000" | jq '.results | .[] | .name') after executing this command its listing first 100 tags of this repository. Actually my repo has more than 1000 image tags. what else need to be added in above command / whats need to done to get all the tags (more than 1000 image tags)

Comment: `IMAGE_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${HUB_TOKEN}" "hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mohd/issues/tags/…" | head -n 300  | jq '.results | .[] | .name')` try this Basically add  `head -n 300`

Comment: But still it showing only 100 image tags after giving head -n 300

Comment: One more solution run `docker-tags "library/ubuntu" | jq --raw-output '.["tags"]'` if you are inside docker container that mean you are already autherized, so just run and access your private repo tags. This might help you 

Comment: but where should i add docker-tags command what is library/ubuntu ?

Comment: but where should i add docker-tags command      IMAGE_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${HUB_TOKEN}" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mohd/issues/tags/?page_size=300" docker-tags "mohd/issues" | jq --raw-output '.["tags"]' '.results | .[] | .name')   OR        IMAGE_TAGS=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: JWT ${HUB_TOKEN}" "hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mohd/issues/tags/?page_size=300" | head -n 300 docker-tags "mohd/issues" | jq --raw-output '.["tags"]' '.results | .[] | .name')                              Just tell me which one is correct if not plse you make and send me Thanks

Comment: ` library/ubuntu ` is for linux , I am showing the example just, Because I don't have your credentials to access your repo, So I cannot send the exact result you want

Comment: ${HUB_TOKEN}" "hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mohd/issues/tags/?page_size=300" docker-tags "mohd/issues" | jq --raw-output '.["tags"]' '.results | .[] | .name') -- is this correct command