# Using one command to list all asp.net docker images

Tags: docker

From [here](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker), we can obtain the images.

[image]

My question would be is there a simple command to list all available images on my Windows desktop?

**EDIT:**

I want to list all available images in the current coreclr framework repository. Based on my Windows desktop .net installation, is the dnu command or docker command to do that?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32622147/4190526

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I find docker image with specific tag in docker registry in docker command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481564/how-can-i-find-docker-image-with-specific-tag-in-docker-registry-in-docker-comma)

Comment: @warmoverflow, it is perhaps a different question. Se my updated.

Comment: Regarding your edit, are you asking whether `dnu` can list docker images available on docker hub, or, are you asking whether the docker cli can list asp.net-core images available on your machine, or someting else?

Comment: @StaffordWilliams, I meant the second one. I want to list asp,net-core images available on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any `grep` available, then you can use `findstr`;

```
c:\git>docker images | findstr /R /C:"microsoft/aspnet"
microsoft/aspnet              1.0.0-rc1-final               c2ddc1b14fd9        3 months ago        742.5 MB
microsoft/aspnet              1.0.0-beta8                   ec21b7401dc2        4 months ago        742.4 MB
microsoft/aspnet              1.0.0-beta7                   cd81e77e42bf        4 months ago        688.4 MB
```

Comment: I want to try the command on my laptop. So step 1, I installed [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox). step 2, I turned off the Windows Firewall. Step 3, run the command. But I got an error `An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.22/images/json/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`