# Listing all version numbers of docker image

Tags: docker

How can I list the tag history of an image?

'docker search ' command lists only the matching images in the registry, not the version (tags). I wanted to know the tag history of the given image.

One way to know this detail is to go to Docker Hub or GitHub folders for the image and deduce previous versions from Dockerfile.

Is it possible to get this info from docker client command line?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to see the list of tagged commits on the image, you can use [Dockviz](https://github.com/justone/dockviz) to do that:

```
$ dockviz images -t
...
├─<missing> Virtual Size: 122.0 MB
│ └─<missing> Virtual Size: 122.4 MB
│   └─<missing> Virtual Size: 122.4 MB
│     └─<missing> Virtual Size: 122.4 MB
│       └─sha256:12543 Virtual Size: 122.4 MB Tags: ubuntu:latest
│         ├─sha256:e807b Virtual Size: 198.1 MB Tags: test/ubuntu:commit2
│         └─sha256:dafd9 Virtual Size: 189.8 MB Tags: test/ubuntu:commit1
```

Comment: Dockviz is a good tool. But it doesnt cater to my requirement. For eg: I wanted to know what are the tags with which ubuntu is available in registry. Like latest, 14.04, 12.04 etc. This list will help me in adding appropriate version in dockerfile or pulling the image without checking docker hub or github.

Comment: @muthu_rk in which case, this is the closest answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32622147/447249